# Combine/merge long YouTube videos

Tags: youtube

YouTube allows to combine multiple videos to create a longer videos using the [Video Editor](https://www.youtube.com/editor). I have uploaded multiple videos to my account but on this page I see only couple of videos in the source list, the one are shorter than 10 min.

Is there a limitation on the length of the source videos, which can be used to make combined longer video?

Answer (score 1):

[The limitation is at 1 hour at the moment](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/183851). Though note that videos that got copyright claims on them aren't available in the editor.